# Remove \n in between double quotes in a CSV using python

Tags: python, csv

I need to remove new line in between the quotes in a csv

Input Ex:

```
 "P.O. Box 160
Big Bay, MI 49808(46.84808584900048, -87.8395882969997)"
```

I need the output as

```
"P.O. Box 160 Big Bay, MI 49808(46.84808584900048, -87.8395882969997)"
```

am trying this but all the lines are vanishing, I think am missing something.. any help here..

```
import csv
with open("input.csv", "rb") as input, open("output.csv", "wb") as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    for record in csv.reader(input):
        w.writerow(tuple(s.remove(""\n"") for s in record))
```

Comment: On 2.7.x, your code snippet first raises a SyntaxError (unexpected character after line continuation character) on `""\n""`, then an AttributeError on `s.remove()`. Please post a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sry, i put the double quote twice..

Answer (score 2):

Use the string.replace method

```
string.replace("\n", "")
```

Comment: Ok, try [i.replace("\n", "") for i in x]